# Jsoup web page parsing - how to avoid ban?

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I've a simple android app, which regularly parses some web page with Jsoup. And my questions:

```
1) can admins detect me? how?
2) how to avoid to be banned?
```

I respect politeness so I set parse interval only every 2 hours, however user can request for manual refresh/parse anytime - but this should happen only few times per day and also to avoid too big traffic I've implemented 10 minutes cache (so maximum possible parse interval is 6x per hour). Is this enough? What if my app will download 1000 users, can they block me?

PS: I'm not parsing complete page with subpages, only 1 html file with size cca 50-100kb.

Comment: Admin can ban you only by IP.Change IP to avoid ban

Comment: But question is, how to be as stealthy as possible (to not attract atention to be banned)? I don't wanna get my app not working, until users reconnect to net again after ban. Some good tips?

Comment: Not authorization user(guest) is a maximum stealthy case.

Comment: so u're saying, that even if my app will download 1000 user, with maximum parse interval 10 minutes it's (almost) impossible to reveal me?

Comment: Jsoup does not accept any authorization.They dont reveal you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the app runs on many different devices with as many different ip addresses they can only detect single users, not you as developer. I think there website should be able to handle that many requests without problems. You're not doing anything normal users might not do...